# How to sync texts and photos in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap site which has 3 photos in a slideshow. The function which does that is:

```
$(function () {
    $.vegas('slideshow', {
        backgrounds: [{
            src: 'img/ph1.jpg', fade: 0, delay: 5000, //fade: 1000, delay: 9000,
        }, {
            src: 'img/ph2.jpg', fade: 0, delay: 5000,
        }, {
            src: 'img/ph3.jpg', fade: 0, delay: 5000,
        },]
    })('overlay', {});
});
```

What I want to do is to associate text for each photo. For example: for `ph1.jpg` to have "text1", for `ph2.jpg` to have "text2", and so on.

I tried to add a carousel in my HTML but the text and the photo are not synchronized (even if they have the same delay). I also tried to modify [this](http://yourjavascript.com/231261314161/jquery-vegas-min.js) JS so to be able to add some text in the above function.

What can I do to get them sync the photos and the text?

Comment: Don't modify the source of a library directly - that's asking for a bad time. A better solution would be to hook to the events the library raises when the slides change and update the text as required. If this library doesn't raise events, then you should look for another one which does.

Comment: I thought it might be a way to add the text property in the library so to can use it in my function. Do you know if there is a way to do that or a library which raises such an event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try better to put your images in a css file and from there to put the text for each other.

Answer (score 1):

You may try below code which rely on `vegaswalk` event callback.

`vegaswalk` event gets triggered whenever Vegas changes the slide. It can be utilized as follows:

```
var textArray = [
    "text1 for ph1.jpg",
    "text2 for ph2.jpg",
    "text3 for ph3.jpg"
];

$("body").on('vegaswalk', function (e, index, slideSettings) {
    var currentText = textArray[index];
    alert(currentText);
    //write here code to set this text in some div present on Page
    //OR
    //write code to move the slide of text carousel as per current index of slideshow
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! For this 'vegaswalk' is it necessary to add another library or anything else in that library which I already have?

Comment: you don't need to add anything to make use of `vegaswalk` trigger. Its already there in vegas.js.

Comment: OK. I will let you know if I have another questions! Thank you!

Comment: Could please give me a hint how could I assign the text to the div? I tried: $('.testScris').textArray(currentText); where '.testScris' is the class i attached to the div, but didn't work.

Comment: its should be done as `$('.testScris').text(currentText); `

Comment: Ok, but the text doesn't change when the new `ph2`, `ph3` appears. The text `"text1 for ph1.jpg"` is displayed for all 3 photos. That is because, I think, of that index. What should I do to fix this? Thanks! :)